# Floyd pattern in c++

Tags: c++

hi i am try to print the following pattern in c++

```
1
2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 10
7 8 9 10
4 5 6
2 3
1
```

using the following loop a print half of it.

```
int i,j,k=1;
cout<<"Enter row";
cin>>n;
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
  for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
  {
    cout<<k<<"\t";
    k++;
  }
}
```

i got the output like

```
1
2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 10
```

how can i print the balance output. but how can i print the mirror of this pattern.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, the code above is wrong, it should be:

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
  for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
  {
    cout<<k<< " ";
    k++;
  }

  cout << '\n';
}
```

Now, to draw the pattern, you could use a loop that would use the following logic:

```
for(;i > 0; i--)
{
    k -= i-1;

    for(j=1;j<i;j++)
    {
        cout <<k<< " ";
        k++;
    }

    cout << '\n';
    k -= i-1;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, just run it on an online compiler. Multiple times. Why?

Comment: @Nishant Still don't see any issue with this code. Why did you ask whether or not I had tested it?

Comment: working fine now, it was giving me some error earlier, and you also said that you noticed some issues.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it was an issue, but realized it was just a formatting matter - it looked like there was an extra number (due to the jump from single digit to double digits), but when I switched from a space to a tab it looked fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    int i, j, k = 1;
    cout << "Enter row";
    cin >> n;
    int elemcount = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        elemcount = 0;
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {

            cout << k << "\t";
            k++;
        }
        cout <<endl;
    }
    k = k - n;      //Reset Counter to the value of the first digit in current row.
    i--;
    j--;
    for (; i > 0; i--)
    {
        j = i;
        elemcount = 0;          //Counter to keep track of elements printed.
        for (; j> 0; j--)
        {
            cout << k << "\t";
            k++;
            elemcount++;
        }
        k = k - elemcount - (i-1); //Resetting K, substracting the number of elements printed and number of elements to be printed in next row.
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: None other I see than giving an answer for such question at all (didn't downvote)

Comment: will be careful next time :(